# Cannot complete the install WebSphere in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, eclipse-plugin, websphere

I can't install WebSphere in eclipse by "Install New Software" with the link:
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/updates/wdt/2020-09_comp/

I probe in eclipse 2020-03 and eclipse 2019-12

I get this error:

```
    Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Web Development Tools    20.0.900.v20200826_1754 (com.ibm.wdt.webtools.top.feature.feature.group 20.0.900.v20200826_1754)
  Missing requirement: Web Development Tools     20.0.900.v20200826_1754 (com.ibm.wdt.webtools.top.feature.feature.group 20.0.900.v20200826_1754) requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; com.ibm.etools.attrview.feature.feature.group 1.0.100' but it could not be found
```

Image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cI5h.png)

I also tried to install IBM WebSphere Application Server V8.5x Developer Tools via Eclipse Marketplace, but failed.

Image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsMCd.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that the server is serving stale content.

Try deleting the folder `~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.oomph.p2/cache`

Comment: It did not work, the installation did not finish.

Comment: no longer shows the option "WebSphere Application Server Developer Tools for Eclipse" to select

Comment: when I try to install it through the Marketplace it shows an error: "The following solutions are not available: IBM WebSphere Application Server V8.5x Developer Tools"

Comment: and when I return to put the previous cache it already shows me the option to download but the problem that I mentioned initially is generated

Comment: I tried with an older eclipse, with the link shown in the image, and I get that error. Image: https://ibb.co/KWFCfWt

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have the wrong link - the Install links at https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-websphere-application-server-v85x-developer-tools#maint-content-area say that for Eclipse 2020-03 and 2019-12 the URL should be https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/updates/wdt/2020-09_comp_was/

[image]